# DataTables order by number field

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

i have a column that represents money values in my [**DataTable Grid**](http://datatables.net/index), how can i order this values correctly, because dataTable order only by the first number like example:

9.000,00

8.000,00

5.454.043,00

4.454.043,00

**of course that it's supposed to be like this:**

5.454.043,00

4.454.043,00

9.000,00

8.000,00

i'm using `number_format` to set my money format.

**php:**

`<td>".number_format($money,2,',','.')."</td>`

any question, be my guest.

Thanks.

---

**edit:**

as answer by @Mikhail , try this, but the column in position [3](http://datatables.net/usage/columns#iDataSort) dont sort any more.

```
 ...
"aoColumnDefs": [
  { "sType": "numeric", "aTargets": [ 3 ] }
],
...
```

---

**edit 2**

little more code:

**php:**

```
while(!$res->EOF){
    ... // post only the 3 <td> position
   <td style='text-align: right;'>".number_format($value,2,',','.')."</td>
   ...
   $res->MoveNext();
}
```

**js DataTable**

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "sScrollY": "225px",
                    "sScrollX": "100%",
                    "sScrollXInner": "100%",
                    "bDestroy" : true,
                    "bScrollCollapse": true,
                    "aoColumnDefs": [
                        { "sType": "numeric", "aTargets": [ 3 ] }
                    ],
                    "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
                    "oTableTools": {
                        "sSwfPath": "js/DataTables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf",
                        "sRowSelect": "single",
                        "aButtons": [
                                        {
                                            "sExtends": "xls",
                                            "sButtonText": "Excel"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "sExtends": "print",
                                            "sButtonText": "Print"
                                        }
                                    ]
                    },
                    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
                    "bPaginate": false
                });
```

---

**Solution**

my solution was create a new column with the value without `number_format`, hidden them like [**this**](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html). Searching some other's way of sort, i fount the [**iDataSort**](http://datatables.net/usage/columns#iDataSort)
now i can format anything in my showing column.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the strings back to float, you could define your own data type for that (untested):

```
(function(){

    var tofloat = function(n) {
        return parseFloat(n.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));
    };

    $.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['mynumeric-asc']  = function(a, b) {
        a = tofloat(a);
        b = tofloat(b)

        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ?  1 : 0));
    };

    $.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['mynumeric-desc'] = function(a, b) {
        a = tofloat(a);
        b = tofloat(b)

        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ?  -1 : 0));
    };

}());
```

then declare `"sType": "mynumeric"`

To compare, this is the whole code for numerical sorting inside DataTables:

```
/*
 * numerical sorting
 */
"numeric-asc": function ( a, b )
{
    var x = (a=="-" || a==="") ? 0 : a*1;
    var y = (b=="-" || b==="") ? 0 : b*1;
    return x - y;
},

"numeric-desc": function ( a, b )
{
    var x = (a=="-" || a==="") ? 0 : a*1;
    var y = (b=="-" || b==="") ? 0 : b*1;
    return y - x;
}
```

As you see, the conversion to number is made by multiplying the string for 1, which does not know about comma or about the dot used as anything but decimal separator.

Comment: So the comma is the culprit? I assumed "numeric" could handle that. I would substitute comma for nothing instead of a period.

Comment: Well, look's like its working now, will make some test's. Return with the result

Comment: yes, see my edit, and consider adding the case for empty cells.

Comment: strange, he keeps sorting by the first number, like: First: 803.448,60, Second: 682,00 Third: 461.404,58, Fourth: 437.621,10. Dont know if i make right but, i only set the `{ "sType": "mynumeric", "aTargets": [ 3 ] }`

Comment: tested right now, should work, though I usually do it for dates. are the comparison functions called at all?

Comment: @Marco Mariani: firebug tell's me `a is not defined` `var x = (a=="-" || a==="") ? 0 : a*1;`

Comment: not sure what you're trying to do. the second part of the response is straight from the DataTables.net sources, to explain how it does numeric sorting. You don't need that.

Comment: well, dont know what is going on, but i did using other way to sort using some ways that datatable give to us, will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can use:

```
natsort($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that the column is "numeric".

http://datatables.net/usage/columns#sType

Good luck!

Comment: yeap, but not working, don't know why but the column just stop sorting. Will update my question.

Comment: Do other columns sort? Are you sure you don't have a generic JS error that prevents other scripts from executing?

Comment: no, aready test in firebug, actually the sort happens, but only with 1 line, all others remains stop.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any more code it's difficult to determine exactly what to do, but the reason why it is performing as it currently is, seems to be due to the `number_format` function. This returns a `string` and therefore the sort is correct. You need to perform the sort before it is converted to a string. But for a more in depth explanation you'd need to provide more in depth code.

Comment: well, i updated my code, i post only a few lines because other thing's i dont think that metter's to much. take a look now.

Comment: and, taking out the number_format, (as i tested before ) the sort work's perfect, but this wont help me.